# ServiceStack.Text version 5.4.0 default char value serialization and deserialization

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-text

This happends JsonSerializer but not with TypeSerializer.

Default char serialization is "\u0000" but deserialization of that string into char is '\'.

Is this a bug? or I am missing something?

Any workaraound? maybe some JsConfig.SerializeFn and JsConfig.DeSerializeFn?

I have done a simple program to test it:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public char AChar { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var obj = new MyObj();
    var json = obj.ToJson();
    System.Console.WriteLine(json);

    var newObj = json.FromJson<MyObj>();

    if (newObj.AChar == obj.AChar)
        System.Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
    else
        System.Console.WriteLine(newObj.ToJson());

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a bug, the serializer just take the first char from the string and converts that. (Doesn't consider to unescape it first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should now be resolved from [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/3b98719e974edf3023090a621aabeeed442a211f).

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).